# What is the difference between a = b and a = b[:]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

Just trying to understand the difference between shallow copies. 
Say I have a list:

```
lst = [1,2,3] 
a = lst
b = lst[:]
```

Can someone please explain the difference between these shallow copy methods.

Comment: `a = lst` it will assign a reference of `lst` to `a` and and `b = lst[:]` this will create new list. Changing `a` changes `lst` but changing `b` doesn't effect `lst`

Comment: These are not shallow copy methods. only `lst[:]` is a shallow copy. Doing `a = lst` simply binds `a` to the same list as `lst`. No copy made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `a` and `b` here is that `a` is another reference to `lst`, but `b` is a reference to a new list. You can see this by modifying `a`. It results that `lst` is modified (since `a` and `lst` refer to the same object), but `b` is not modified.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3] 
>>> a = lst
>>> b = lst[:]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0] = 3
>>> a
[3, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> lst
[3, 2, 3]
```

However, although the operator `[:]` creates a copy rather than a reference, it still creates a *shallow copy*, which means that the copy is only one layer deep. In particular, this means that if the elements of the list are more complex objects, those objects will not be copied, but will just be references to the same objects in the new list. This can be seen by trying the same thing with a list of lists:

```
>>> list2
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> list3 = list2
>>> list4 = list2[:]
>>> list3
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> list4
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> list4[0][0] = 2
>>> list3
[[2, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> list4
[[2, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Notice that modifying an *element of the element* of the list `list4` also modifies `list3`. This is because although they are different lists, their first elements both refer to the same list.

Comment: thanks for layering it out. So I would need to make a deepcopy for list4 if I wanted to change the contents without affecting the original list2 and list3?

Comment: @td1 That is correct!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example to show the difference. Basically, `a=lst` is a pointer from `a` to list `lst`, so when you subsequently modify list `a` list `lst` is modified equally. `a=lst[:]` is a copy of list `lst`. So subsequent modification of `a` has no effect on list `lst`.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=a
>>> b[1]='x'
>>> b
[1, 'x', 3]
>>> a
[1, 'x', 3]
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> c=a[:]
>>> c[1]='x'
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c
[1, 'x', 3]
```

Comment: thank you! appreciate the demonstration