# For loop not iterating through all values in list?

Tags: python, for-loop

Trying to troubleshoot this code and am getting a bizarre output.  Can someone explain why the outermost for loop is not running for i=2?  Thanks!

For context, the code was written to try to delete all values in b from a, including all repeats (i.e. a=[1,2,2], b=[2] should output [1]).  I know there are more efficient ways to do it I just am confused why this doesn't work.

**Code:**

```
def arrayfunc(a,b):
    list = a
    for i in a:
        print(i)
        for j in b:
            if i == j:
                list.remove(j)
    print(a)

arrayfunc([1,2,3],[1])
```

**Output**

```
1
3
[2, 3]
```

Comment: can you format your code properly?

Comment: you're deleting from the list while iterating over it.

Comment: Don't call a list `list` since doing so overwrites a name which has a built-in meaning

Comment: return [i for i in a if i not in set(b)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the list `a` into `list` (although you should use a name other than `list` since it's a built-in) as `list=a.copy()` or `list=a[:]`. Currently you are just pointing `list` to `a`, so when you modify `list` you also modify `a`.

See this answer: [What is the difference between a = b and a = b[:]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61797651/what-is-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-b/61797750#61797750)